# How to split String and put it on ArrayList?

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

here is my **String**. [NOT A Arraylist]

```
[1], [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], [22630]
```

How to convert it to Arraylist as belows

```
item 01 : [1]
item 02 : [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>]
item 03 :  [22630]
```

**EDITED**

```
[1], [<2254... here also matched ", "
...0720,C,D>,<2254,890... here also matched ", "
```

so that split `item 02` incorrectly.

Comment: have you tried regex???

Comment: (1) Split to array of strings, (2) convert to ArrayList<String>

Comment: Is it always the case that "external delimiter is `, ` (comma plus space), while "internal" just `,` (comma)?

Comment: yes dear  PM 77-1.its list of arraylists [return from web service as string]

Comment: dear ray if i used ur one its not given the real solution.
ex : item number 02

Comment: dear Pulah Nandha.i'm still beginner level at regex :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 * @author JFVARUGH
 * here is my String. [NOT A Arraylist] [1],
 *  [1],
 *  [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], ...
 *
 *item 01 : [1]
  item 02 : [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>]
  item 03 : [22630]
 */
public class StringProblel {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int index =0, tempIndex=0,stringIndex=0;
        char[] keyWrds =  {'[',']',','};
        char[][] temp = new char[1000][1000];

        String sourceStr = "[1],[<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], [22630] ";

        while(index < sourceStr.length()){
            if( sourceStr.charAt(index) == keyWrds[0] ){
                temp[stringIndex][tempIndex] = sourceStr.charAt(index);
                while(sourceStr.charAt(index) != keyWrds[1] && index < sourceStr.length()){
                    index++;
                    temp[stringIndex][++tempIndex] = sourceStr.charAt(index);                   
                }

                stringIndex++;              
            }
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(temp[1]);
    }

}


The time complexity will be O(n2). There is scope for improvements !
```

I have complied it is working.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
String s = "[1], [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], [22630]";
```

Then using the [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) along with a [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on the seperator `", "`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(", ")));
```

To your comment, are you sure?

```
String itemTwo = "[<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>]";
System.out.println(itemTwo.equals(list.get(1)));
```

Returns

```
true
```

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(", ")));

Comment: dear arynaq & Gokul Nath, if i used ur one its not given the real solution. ex : item number 02

Comment: Please see the edit. @GokulNath That I omitted because I assumed JRE7, will edit it though cannot be sure what JRE he is on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much simpler solution using Regular expressions.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class TestRegularExpression2 {

    private static String input = "[1], [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], [22630]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Matches everything between the braces                
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);   

        // Prints out each of the matching strings. 
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("*" + matcher.group() + "*");
        }

    }

}
```

Output of this is

`*[1]*` 
`*[<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>]*`
`*[22630]*`

Comment: wow dear Swaroop.issue sorted.
now i use both solution in two places :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "[1], [<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>,<2254,89014103211118510720,C,D>], [22630]";

List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String s1 : str.split(", ")) {
    aList.add(s1);
}
```

Comment: dear Gokul, i edited the question.its not given the item 02 correctly as per ur solution also